# Problems connecting to RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium

I'm investigating running our selenium webdriver tests on a remote machine, but having issues connecting.  Here's what I'm doing:

From the client machine with the test.  I setup the driver like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
WebDriver driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.2.15:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

On the server machine with the browser to be tested I start both the hub and node like this:

Start hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
```

Start node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

I checked the grid console and verified the node is connected.  The server is a Win 7 32 bit machine running IE8.  I've also tried IE9, but I haven't been able to connect to it either.  I've shut off Windows Firewall in case that was blocking the connection, but that didn't seem to make a difference.  The IP of the server machine is 10.0.2.15.

The exception I'm hitting happens when I try to create the RemoteWebDriver:

```
WebDriver driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.2.15:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver`

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem here is that my hub and node are running in a virtualbox VM and the network adapter needed to be set to Bridged Adapter rather than the default NAT setting.  Once I made that change I had no problems connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a internet explorer present on the node ?
if you specify capabilities, the target must match with it.
you can check nodes and availables capabilities using

```
http://localhost:4444/grid/console
```

Updated : 
It seems you're not using the same version of selenium on the server and in your java project.
It should work using selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar for your server and nodes.

I hope it may help you

Comment: Yeah, it shows one Internet Explorer icon and five chrome and firefox icons for the node for both the Remote Control and WebDriver.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that would do it, but still hitting the same exception.  I've updated my post to show the new version of the standalone jar being used.  One thing I'm noticing is that I am unable to start IEDriverServer.exe manually.  I have it in Windows\System32 and when I manually start it, I get an error: Failed to start the server with: port = '5555', host = '', log level = '', log file = ''.

Comment: Hm, ok the IEDriverServer wasn't starting because it was defaulting to port 5555, which is was my standalone node was currently binded to. It starts up fine if I give it a different port.  So, reading through the IEDriverServer docs, I see it doesn't currently support remote connections.  So, does that mean it is not needed if I am using the selenium-server-standalone jar?

Comment: Did you tried with another browser ? It's seems to be a problem with IE.

Answer (score 0):

When you starts the node you should specify the location of the iedriver, example:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:/<pathtoyouriedriver>/IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://<hub_ip>:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,maxInstances=10"
```